# How I can add an item to an array items of a column in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

this is data from the skills column of the resumes table:

```
{"en_title":"resume title in english","en":["item 1","item 2"]}
```

I want to update the `en` column in livewire. I can add an item to the `en` array but can't save or update the database. this is livewire Class:

```
    public Resume $resume;
    public $en;

    protected $rules = [
        'en' => 'string',
    ];

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();

    $items = $this->resume->skills['en'];
    $items[] = $this->en;
    $this->resume->update(['skills.en' => $items]);
    }
```

And View:

```
    <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
           <input type="text" wire:model.defer="en">
           <button type="submit">ADD</button>
    </form>
```

dd of `$this->resume->skills['en']` is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "item 1"
  1 => "item 2"
]
```

And dd of `$items[] = $this->en` is:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "item 1"
  1 => "item 2"
  2 => "new item"
]
```

but can't save in database by:  `$this->resume->update(['skills.en' => $items]);`
I think the `skills.en` name has problem but can't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->resume->update([
  'skills' => [
    'en' => $items
  ],
]);
```